# Unable to find a specification for `ExpoModulesCore` depended upon by `Expo`

Tags: react-native, expo, podspec

I am trying to add expo dependencies (`media-library` and `mail-composer` to be exact) to a React Native Project. I `yarn add`ed both dependencies as well as `yarn add expo-modules@latest` and `yarn add expo-modules-core`. Then I ran `npx pod-install` and just to be safe, as `cd`'d into `iOS` and ran `pod install`. Both `pod` commands failed and gave the following error:

```
Couldn't install: Expo » ExpoModulesCore. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Unable to find a specification for `ExpoModulesCore` depended upon by `Expo`
```

I deleted `node_modules`, `iOS/Pods`, `iOS/build`, and `yarn.lock`, I reinstalled everything with `yarn` and then tried again, to get the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was avoiding using `npm install` or `npx install` in order to keep everything on yarn, BUT there is one command you need to run with `npx`.
Its `npx install-expo-modules`, once I ran that everything was fixed

Comment: how does the doc and github not have anything on this??! solved this for me!

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/